# SAP Marketing and custom back-end connection

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, sap-marketing-cloud

We are using **SAP marketing** to manage push notification campaign, we need to implement a solution as Middleware or something else to save the notification data in our server through an **API**. This way the user can see notification history in application.

Is it to possible to do it by a custom Development within **SAP marketing**, or we should find different way?

Comment: Why did you tag Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)? (ex GCM) Also there are several marketing products by SAP, which exact software are you talking about?

Comment: @SandraRossi im talking about SAP Marketing cloud , and i tagged FCM cause it's the one used by that product for push notification